# WINSOCK Connection in C#

Tags: c#, server, connection, winsock, pbx

I am working in visual studio 2015 C# windows application. I connect the winsock to c# application to get the incoming call data from server.
Here i explained clearly what i done for this.

**Connecting the WINSOCK control to my form**

Right click on toolbox->choose items

[image]

**code:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CLIENT
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.w1.Error += new AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ErrorEventHandler(this.w1_Error);
            this.w1.ConnectEvent += new System.EventHandler(this.w1_ConnectEvent);
            this.w1.DataArrival += new AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEventHandler(this.w1_DataArrival);
        }
        Boolean isConnected = false;

        private void w1_ConnectionRequest(object sender, AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ConnectionRequestEvent e)
        {
            if (isConnected == true)
            {
                w1.Close();
            }
            w1.Accept(e.requestID);
            isConnected = true;
            DataInput.Text += "\n - Client Connected :" + w1.RemoteHostIP;
        }


        private void w1_ConnectEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataInput.Text += "\n - Connect Event : " + w1.RemoteHostIP;
            isConnected = true;
        }

        private void w1_DataArrival(object sender, AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEvent e)
        {
            String data = "";
            Object dat = (object)data;
            w1.GetData(ref dat);
            data = (String)dat;
            DataInput.Text += "\nServer - " + w1.RemoteHostIP + " : " + data;
        }

        private void w1_Error(object sender, AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ErrorEvent e)
        {
            DataInput.Text += "\n- Error : " + e.description;
            isConnected = false;
        }

        private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                w1.Close();
                w1.Connect(IPText.Text, PortText.Text);
            }
            catch (System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException g)
            {
                DataInput.Text += "\n" + g.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I need to connect the pbx server 10.0.0.68.
please help me why its not connected ? why it gives some error ?? some one help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use that control and not just regular Socket?

Comment: @Anjana thank you for asking this question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is server side, not client side.

Most common reasons:

1) The server is not listening on the specified port

2) Also, maybe there is a firewall problem

Check your server code and make sure it is always in the listening mode.

A lot of programmers do not allow the server to return back to the listening mode or not listening at all on startup, very common mistake in coding.

The server should always be listening for a connection. When one comes in the server accepts the connection, opens up a new socket for that client, not the server's main socket which must be only used for listening and establishing the connection, and then the server must return back to the listening mode.

Comment: data are falls into that ip- 10.0.0.68 and port-514  in which format ? i mean log files or excel or table ?

Comment: @Pranav Patel hii sir I am also have the same problem if u know please help me to solve.

Comment: @Karthi and Anjana It really depends on what brand/model your PBX system is (Siemens, Splicecom, Alcatel, whatever...) - they usually offer some form of documentation/protocol description etc. - Splicecom for example has several protocols providing different information which you can access to achieve what you describe. Similar things exist for Siemens and others too... with some vendors/models these interfaces need to be licensed additionally.

Comment: So without having some valuable information, i can't help you much, yaa but i will help if you will stuck in between logically